# Is there a way to make Windows Powershell 6 my default terminal?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, prompt, powershell-6.0

I downloaded pwsh 6, or pwsh core, and wanted to make it default.

Currently whenever I use the shorcut for a CMD, I already get the old pwsh, but I wanted to use the new one instead.

Is there anyway to do it?

Maybe through env variables, or something similar?

I can't seem to find anything about this specific topic anywhere...

Comment: PowerShell V6 exists alongside PowerShell V5.  Go to the Start Menu, Windows Powershell, right click, More, File location and adjust File location to the V6 location, save it and test.

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate things, on purpose and by design. Designed to run side-by-side for a reason. Windows for the foreseeable future will always default to Butlin v5. There are no public plans for MS to change this.

If you don't modify the shortcuts to point to pwsh.exe vs powershell.exe as John is saying, that is what you'll get.

The other step to do is to change .ps* extension association to pwsh.exe Just right-click any .ps1, *.psm1, *.psd, etc... and properties, change the 'Open With' to pwsh.exe vs powershell.exe.

If you are still using the ISE, then follow the instructions below to use pwsh.exe from the ISE.

If you are using VSCode, then change your settings to default to pwsh.exe.

Even if you do this for yourself, you must always write your code to be downlevel compatible, because unless PSCore is on your targets as well, you will run into issues.

Pointers relative to context above:

> [VSCode as a console for PowerShell Core 6 - Use Multiple shells](https://4sysops.com/archives/vscode-as-a-console-for-powershell-core-6-part-1-multiple-shells)
>
> [How to use PowerShell Core with Visual Studio Code](https://www.iannoble.co.uk/use-powershell-core-visual-studio-code)
>
> [Simplified ISE-like UI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/vscode/how-to-replicate-the-ise-experience-in-vscode?view=powershell-6#simplified-ise-like-ui)
>
> If you're looking to simplify the Visual Studio Code UI to look more
>   closely to the UI of the ISE, apply these two settings:
>
> [How To Make Visual Studio Code Look And Behave Like The PowerShell
>   ISE](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vscode%20like%20ise)
>
> [Using Powershell Core 6 and 7 in the Windows PowerShell ISE](https://ironmansoftware.com/using-powershell-core-6-and-7-in-the-windows-powershell-ise)